# jQuery Backstretch not displaying correctly when used on the layout-page

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

within my asp.net Mvc 4 application I'm using datepicker to allow the user to select a date as input for a textbox.
I set several attributes to ensure the user picks either to days date or a previous, this works fine...
Now all I want to do is display todays date in the textbox when the user first visit's the page as more often then not todays date will be selected, so it will act like a default but will be visible straight away without the user selecting the textbox...

Any ideas...?
Thanks.

jQuery..

```
    $("#dischargedatepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'D dd M yy',
        maxDate: 0,
        highlightWeek: true,
        showAnim: "scale",
        showOptions: {
            origin: ["top", "left"]
        }
    });
```

Html..

```
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Appointment, new { @id = "dischargedatepicker" ,@class = "span12 m-wrap"})
```

Comment: Do you want to have default date inside a textbox?

Comment: yes, but it has to be recognized as valid input, so it is saved to the db correctly ..as would any selected date...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about?:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public DateTime Appointment;

   public MyModel()
   {
      Appointment = DateTime.Now;
   }
}
```

Just set default date on serverside in a constructor.

Comment: I would do like that.

Comment: Is there no way of using the likes of a placeholder and set to DateTime.Today ??

Comment: @mkell As far as I understand, you are using jquery datepicker. I user would like to change date he will put focus on textbox and see datepicker. And then he will be able to change date. What else do you wish?

Comment: I already had ....Appointment = DateTime.Now.ToString(),...in my model, I wish to see that value displayed in the textbox when I view the page...

Comment: I'm afraid not..it's not displaying, I'll keep at it and post answer if I get it, thanks

Comment: Got if, added a few break points to track it down , basically there is two similar controllers, so apologies Andrei , you were dead right...thanks guys (it's Friday afternoon, long week)

Comment: @mkell happy for you :)